# check Claim array for specific value

Tags: .net-core, blazor

if i have

```
services.AddAuthorization(config =>
            {
                 config.AddPolicy("IsDeveloper", policy => policy.RequireClaim("developer","true"));                                
            });
```

my JWT token contains

```
"permissions": [        
    "customer_get",
    "customer_update",
    "customer_create",
    "customer_delete",
    "developer"
  ]
```

And then i try to protect my blazor site with:

```
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "IsDeveloper")]

    <AuthorizeView Policy="IsDeveloper">
        <p>You can only see this if you're an admin or superuser.</p>
    </AuthorizeView>
```

what have i done wrong in this implementation? Can't requireClaim be used this way? i have to do something different here?

it works when my JWT token only contains:

```
"permissions": "developer"
```

so i can ofc. just add them as, Name = true.. but though the array was easier to read

Comment: IMO you should use `Authorize` attribute xor `AuthorizeView` not both at the same time. You setup looks good, but do you use `AddAuthorizationCore` or `AddAuthorization` ?

Comment: @aguafrommars you are right, i only tested to see if it changed anything trying one or another. I'm using AddAuthorization.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code please

Comment: You can use `policy.RequireAssertion` instead or create a Policy handler

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old post but I spent a while trying to figure it out as well so here's my solution. Same concept, I had a jwt with several 'claims', Id, username, role etc etc.

```
{
  "id": "4d2ds1fg-12da-4fg6-f57h-34gdfg33g33f",
  "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
  "username": "joe@bloggs.com",
  "firstname": "Joe",
  "surname": "Bloggs",
  "role": "admin",
  "claims": [
    "CanCreateAccounts",
    "CanDeleteAccounts"
  ],
  "nbf": 1662110501,
  "exp": 1662111101,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5000",
  "aud": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

It wasn't until I saw the comment from @agua from mars (idk how to tag) that i figured out about the policy.RequireAssertion method.

So in my action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route(nameof(CreateAccount))]
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.CreateAccounts)] //string ref = "CreateAccountsPolicy"
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAccount([FromBody] NewAccountRequest request)
{
        // verify request data and create an account...
}
```

And then in Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
o.AddPolicy(Policies.CreateAccounts,
    p => p.RequireAssertion(context => AssertClaim(context, Claims.CanCreateAccounts)));
});
```

Finally have a private method to validate the array of claims:

```
private static bool AssertClaim(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, string claim)
{
    if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == Claims.ClaimsString)) return false;
    var claims = context.User.FindAll(x => x.Type == Claims.ClaimsString);
    var correctClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == claim);
    return correctClaim != null;
}
```

n.b. The Claims and Policy classes are just custom string references